# В чем ошибка?

Tags: pascal

Задача - вычислить последовательность литер `d1+d2-d3*d4`

```
program piu1;
var
d1,d2,d3,d4:Char;
s:Integer;
begin
Writeln<''Считает d1+d2-d3*d4''>;
Writeln<'Введите исходные данные:'>;
Write<'d1= '>;
Readln<d1>;
Write<'d2= '>;
Readln<d2>;
Write<'d3= '>;
Readln<d3>;
Write<'d4= '>;
Readln<d4>;
s:=ord<d1>+ord<d2>-ord<d3>*ord<d4>;
Writeln<s>;
Writeln<'Нажмите Enter для выхода'>;
End.
```

Comment: Я, конечно, уже не помню тонкости приведения типов в Паскале, но почему вы объявляете и вводите переменный Char, а считаете сумму Int?

Comment: Также неясно, почему вместо `(`, `)` используются `<`, `>`; стоит начать с этого.

Comment: Он делает `Ord()`, так что это нормально, ЕМНИП, `Ord('1') = 1`. Только это сработает только для чисел от 0 до 9, иначе ему надо `String` а не `Char`.

Вообще, надо писать не «почему не работает», а что делается и что возникает за ошибка.

Comment: вообще то ord('1') не равно 1.

Comment: И правда, попутал, простите. `StrToInt()` ему надо, если компилятор умеет. Или `Ord(x) - Ord('0')` aka `Ord(x) - 48`, на худой конец.

Comment: Ребят, паскаль читает инты =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
program piu1;
var
  d1, d2, d3 , d4, s: integer;
begin
Writeln('-----------------------------');
Writeln('Введите исходные данные:');
Write('d1= ');Readln(d1);
Write('d2= ');Readln(d2);
Write('d3= ');Readln(d3);
Write('d4= ');Readln(d4);
s:=d1 + d2 - d3 * d4;
Writeln('-----------------------------');
Write('d1 + d2 - d3 * d4 = ');
Writeln(s);
Writeln('-----------------------------');
Writeln('Нажмите Enter для выхода');
Readln;
End.
```